# How can I use DECLARE clause in a statement on jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I am currently trying to use a DECLARE clause in a preparedStatent with jdbc. The code that I wrote is:

```
         statement.executeUpdate(" declare @variable int set @variable = "+timer+" INSERT INTO table1 values (ip, protocol, counter, timer) SELECT ip,protocol,counter,@variable FROM table2 ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0 ;");
```

What I'm trying to get is to create a new table (that is table1) which includes the top 5 from table2 (every 5 secs e.g), with a predefined interval. The interval is the timer variable. The timer variable is passed through a method.

Note: I don't know if it makes any difference to use preparedStatement. I tried both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need to create a new table from a select, then you should use this query instead:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 SELECT ip,protocol,counter,@variable FROM table2 ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

But if you do this in Java and using `PreparedStatement` then you can pass the value of `@variable` as a parameter, thus getting rid of the previous query. So, your query will look like this in Java code:

```
String sql =
    "CREATE TABLE table1"
    + " SELECT ip,protocol,counter,?"
    + " FROM table2"
    + " ORDER BY counter DESC"
    + " LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0";
```

Assuming you already have the table `table1` created and you're just adding the latest results into it from `table2`, then the query will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 values (ip, protocol, counter, timer) SELECT ip,protocol,counter,@variable FROM table2 ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

Again, you can pass the value of `@variable` as a parameter. The query will look like this in Java code:

```
String sql = 
    "INSERT INTO table1 (ip, protocol, counter, timer)"
    + " SELECT ip,protocol,counter,?"
    + " FROM table2"
    + " ORDER BY counter DESC"
    + " LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0";
```

Then, you will prepare the query like this:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
//setting your variable as the parameter in the query
pstmt.setString(1, timer);
```

In the end, you will use `PreparedStatement#execute` or `PreparedStatement#executeUpdate`:

```
//the former query is a DDL query
pstmt.execute();
//the latter query is a DML query
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You cannot parameterize column _names_, only _values_ over JDBC.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I've tested the code before posting the answer.

Comment: Ok, it seems you can do that in the `SELECT` for an `INSERT`, then. Support for this feature might be vendor-specific?

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes, it depends on the database vendor.

Comment: So it depends on my database vendor? because I get an error for bad syntax. @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: @giorgos I've tested it against MySQL 5.5 and works as expected. I must check the code you're using to check what error you're getting.

Comment: preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO  thesis.top values (ip, protocol, counter, timer) SELECT ip,protocol,counter,? FROM thesis.SYN ORDER BY counter DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;");
     preparedStatement.setDouble(1, timer );
     preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

Comment: my bad. I forgot the values clause.

Comment: @giorgos if you're using `INSERT INTO <TABLE> SELECT ...` you don't need to use `VALUES` at all, as shown in my answer.